# Elementary Algebra Problem (in 8th grade)

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The exercise is to prove that $$ \forall x \in [0,3] $$ : $$ f(x)=\sqrt{18 + 3x -x^{2}} + \sqrt{9-x^{2}} + \sqrt{9-6x+x^{2}} + \sqrt{9x-3x^{2}} \le 12 $$

I notice that when $$ x=0 \implies f(x) = 3\sqrt{2} + 3 + 3 \le 12 $$ 
and when $$ x=3 \implies f(x) = 3\sqrt{2} \le 12 $$, but how further?

Comment: What tools are available to your 8th grade student?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$f(x)=\sqrt{(6-x)(3+x)}+\sqrt{(3-x)(3+x)}+\sqrt{(3-x)^2}+\sqrt{3x(3-x)}$$

$\forall x\in [0,3]$, the factors $6-x$, $3+x$, $3-x$ and $3x$ in the radicands are **non-negative**.

By $GM\le AM$,

$$f(x)\le \frac{(6-x)+(3+x)}{2}+\frac{(3-x)+(3+x)}{2}+3-x+\frac{3x+(3-x)}{2}=12$$

> Note that $12$ is not the global maximum, but a resonable upper bound.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The solution is ok, because 8th graders know the inequality between geometrical and arithmetical mean.

Comment: It's not easy to see the trick of summing the factors.  It's challenging though elementary.

Comment: Summing the factors? that's a good trick, but where is that from? Is there somewhere I can read up more on that? I can't seem to find that anywhere...

Answer (score 0):

**Hints:**

Each radicand is a quadratic polynomial which has a *maximum* (the corresponding parabola is oriented downwards) or a *minimum*  (the corresponding parabola is oriented upwards). The extremum of $ax^2+bx+c\;$ is obtained at  $x=-\dfrac b{2a}$.

Comment: Not really: the third one is $9-6x+x^2$.

Comment: @egreg: Right. I should have read the entire line. I'll change that within a second. Thanks for pointing it.